# Sprites disappears sometimes [Sprite Kit]

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sprite-kit

Main menu looks like this.

[image: Main menu]

When i press start code below changes the scene.

```
    let newScene = LevelScene(size: self.scene!.size)
    let transition = SKTransition.revealWithDirection(SKTransitionDirection.Up, duration: 1)

    newScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFill
    self.scene!.view!.presentScene(newScene, transition: nil)
```

And after I return to the main menu it looks like this

[image: Main menu =(]
or this
[image]

So, as you can see, sprites just disappears. I can't come up with a reason for this to happen.

Comment: Maybe you need to increase the zPosition of the nodes that disappear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you doing,

```
self.addChild(...)
self.addChild(...)
```

in your didMoveToView method? 
Another possible problem might be that you are setting the zPosition of the node to less than your background, and / or other nodes.

Comment: Well, this sounds rational. Thank you for answer!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with sprites disappearing and after changing the zPositions of all my sprites and background I still wasn't able to solve it.

I ended up just redeclaring the scene inside my restartButton:

```
var scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")

scene?.scaleMode = .aspectFill

view!.presentScene(scene)
```

And that worked for me.